# The order of execution of setState in hooks

Tags: reactjs

React version: 17.0.2

Steps To Reproduce
code

```
function useStateStore(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);
  let newState = state;
  const setStateWrap = (value, callback) => {
    setState(state => {
      console.log("state", state);
      newState = { ...state, ...value };
      console.log("newState", newState);
      callback && callback(newState);
      return newState;
    });
    return newState;
  };

  const getState = () => newState;

  return {
    state,
    setStateWrap,
    getState
  };
}
    
function App(){
  const {state, setStateWrap,getState} = useStateStore({time:1})

  function handleClick(){
    setStateWrap({time: state.time+1})
    console.log('state.time===>',state.time);
    console.log('getState.time===>',getState().time);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>button-time</button>
      <div>time-{state.time}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Link to code example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-mopsa-q6ju7?file=/src/App.js

### The current behavior

first clicked button get the result

```
state {time: 1}
newState {time: 2}
state.time===> 1
getState.time===> 2
```

second clicked button get the result

```
state.time===> 2
getState.time===> 2
state {time: 2}
newState {time: 3}
```

### The expected behavior

first clicked button get the result

```
state.time===> 1
getState.time===> 2
state {time: 1}
newState {time: 2}
```

second clicked button get the result

```
state.time===> 2
getState.time===> 2
state {time: 2}
newState {time: 3}
```

I want to know why have different order in two click action?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way that React internally handles its events queue. That first update is eagerly computed. From react-dom.development.js dispatchAction function:

```
if (fiber.lanes === NoLanes && (alternate === null || alternate.lanes === NoLanes)) {
  // The queue is currently empty, which means we can eagerly compute the
  // next state before entering the render phase. If the new state is the
  // same as the current state, we may be able to bail out entirely.

  ...
```

Ideally, if you want to use any functionality after updating a state you should use the useEffect hook as is indicated by some React console errors:

```
console.error(
        "State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " +
          'second callback argument. To execute a side effect after ' +
          'rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().',
      );
```

So, if you want your code to execute always in the same order, you should change your code and include a useEffect hook